# If $A,B,C$ are three sets then prove that $(A\Delta B) \Delta C=A\Delta( B \Delta C) $(, where $\Delta $ is the symmetric differences i.e $A\Delta B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was studying set theory . There was a problem in the book which states that: If $A,B,C$ are three sets then prove that $(A\Delta B) \Delta C=A\Delta( B \Delta C) $(, where $\Delta $  is the symmetric differences i.e $A\Delta B=(A-B)\cup (B-A)$)

If we try to solve it by expansion (i.e by writing it in $A\Delta B=(A-B)\cup (B-A)$ form )it  becomes a huge lengthy expression . Is that the only way? Can it be proved like that? I am not quite been able to solve it in that approach either. Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: You can show it with a simple drawing !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be solved in *combinatorial* language: $B\triangle C$ represents the elements that are exactly included in one of $B$ or $C$, and thus $A\triangle (B\triangle C)$ represents those elements that appear exactly once in $A$ and $B\triangle C$, which are just the ones which appear *exactly once or three times* in $A$, $B$ and $C$. Since this equivalent transformation is symmetric, the equation is therefore proven.

The way you've mentioned is also solvable, but with analyzing *every element* in both the left and the right hand sides.

Comment: So u r basically saying that we also get the same conclusion from $(A\Delta B)\Delta C$ that it contains all the elements which have appeared once or thrice in $A,B $and$ C$, right? So they become equivalent and thus the relation holds true, right? Thank you so much...

Comment: Yes, you're right!

Comment: @erpxyr2001...I do get it now...Thank you so much!...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to translate the operations on sets to operations on their [indicator functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function). $\Delta$ corresponds to addition modulo 2 (which is obviously associative).

Comment: Can you please say what do u mean by "addition modulo 2"?

Comment: (I see that @drhab gave the same answer half an hour later.) [Addition modulo 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n) is$$0+0=0,\;0+1=1+0=1,\;1+1=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

It is not difficult to verify that for any element $x$:$$1_{A\Delta B}\left(x\right)\equiv1_{A}\left(x\right)+1_{B}\left(x\right)\mod2$$
On base of that we find that:$$1_{(A\Delta B)\Delta C}(x)\equiv1_{A\Delta(B\Delta C)}(x)\mod2$$which is the same statement as:$$1_{(A\Delta B)\Delta C}(x)=1_{A\Delta(B\Delta C)}(x)$$